# How to use getResources() function in a Library module in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on a library module for my main code, which should be capable of using GPIO pins to show different figures, letters and symbols on a 7-segment-display. I use the `res` folder to save information about which element to turn on in an array. Now I want to import the `array.xml` into a class in the library module.

I tried to use:

```
public class SevenDisplay{
    public SevenDisplay(){
        TypedArray figureCode = getResources().getIdentifier("array", "id", "com.library.package");
    }
}
```

but it tells me:

```
Cannot resolve method getResources()
```

Is there a way to get the array from the `array.xml` into my library module?

Comment: you need to pass context in library and use it.

Comment: You can't use method in a class until someone declares it. In case of your code, that class is new, so you can only use methods declared by `java.lang.Object` type unless you declare your own methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your `class` don't know what the heck is `getResources()`. So it raise an error.

As `Context` has the `getResources()` method as an `Instance Method`, you have to get the `context`, So for that add a parameter in the constructor of your class for context, like so:

```
public class SevenDisplay {

    public SevenDisplay(Context context) {
        TypedArray figureCode = context.getResources().getIdentifier("array", "id", "com.library.package");
    }
}
```

And when you create instance of this then pass `context` like so:

```
SevenDisplay sevendisplay = new SevenDisplay(YourActivity.this);
```

This will help you out and the error would be removed.

Comment: In that case I get the resources from the ContextActivities res folder, right?

Comment: @DerOta I think one and only one `res` folder exists in a project